# How do I show an ng-repeat item that has already been hidden

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-hide

I have an ng-repeat that looks like this:

```
<div class="name" ng-hide="name.hide" ng-repeat="name in nameArray" ng-click="checkName(name)">
```

When one of the ng-repeat elements is clicked, I need it to be hidden so, in my controller, I'm doing this:

```
$scope.checkName = function(name){
   name.hide = true;
}
```

That all works fine but I need to figure out a way to show all hidden ng-repeat items again after the user leaves this view and then returns to it from another view.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is `response` in `ng-hide="response.hide"`? everywhere else you are dealing with `name`....

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant to type name.hide. I edited my question.

Comment: Isn't `nameArray` destroyed once you navigate away from your view ? Meaning it gets rebuilt when you come back and they should all be visible again ?

Comment: I thought that's how things worked as well but when I navigate back from another view, the hidden items are still hidden.

Comment: That's how it works, but apparently your data resides in a controller that is still active when you navigate to a different route. Perhaps that's a controller on an outer scope of your ui-route.

Comment: Or maybe that data is in a service, and that's why it's kept when your controller is destroyed. If that's the case I'll draft up an answer for you.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not using ui-router. I'm using ngRoute. Could that be causing my controller to remain active, even though I'm assigning unique controllers to my views in my app.config?

Comment: Yes, Omri! My data IS in a service. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is indeed in a service (which is why it is kept alive, since services are singletons and do not get destroyed as you navigate between routes), then you can do a sort of a reset to the hide property when you navigate away from your view.

Place this in your controller code:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
     angular.forEach(nameArray, function (item) {
          item.hide = false;
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Omri, your insight led me to the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store all the hidden name in a service and have a lookup in the controller each time a view use the controller.